# how to model and verify model

Tags: logic, automata, formal-verification, automata-theory, uppaal

I have written several requirements formally for modeling a real-time system. One of these requirements is as follows:
If `sensor1.value` is less than or equal to -5 and `sensor2.value` is less than or equal to 2, then eventually, after some time, `sensor2.value` will be greater than 2.
The formal representation of these requirements in LTL or TCTL is as follows:
`Globally ((sensor2.value <= 2 and sensor1.value <= -5) -> EVENTUALLY sensor2.value > 2)`.

Based on this and other requirements, I have designed the following automaton(x is time variable).
[image]
My first question is whether I should consider the values of sensors as channels in the synchronization section of the automaton or as data variables in the guard section?

Now I want to see if my requirements are satisfied by timed automata or not. The automaton itself has no syntax errors. However, in the verifier section, I don't know how to write the queries.

Query for the case where sensor values are considered as data variables in the automaton:
`A[]((automaton1.sensor1 <= 5) imply E<>(automaton1.sensor2 > 2))`

When executing this formula, I encountered the following error.
Unexpected T_EF
[image]

In the second case, I also don't know how to design the query."

I just have some LTL formulas, and a Timed Automata(TA). (It's closer to mathematical definition of TA. no need to channel concept)
I need to verify if TA satisfies formulas or not?